# What could cause factory-bot to not properly associate uploaded file fields in Big Sur

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, macos-big-sur

Upon upgrading to Big Sur specs utilizing `fixture_file_upload` are not working.

My test model has file details such as

```
    t.string "report_file_name"
    t.string "report_content_type"
    t.integer "report_file_size"
    t.datetime "report_updated_at"
```

The skinny version of my factory:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :test do
    report { fixture_file_upload "#{Rails.root}/spec/factories/paperclip/test_report.pdf", 'application/pdf' }
  end
end
```

Stack Trace:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Report content type is invalid, Report is invalid
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/configuration.rb:18:in `block in initialize'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/evaluation.rb:18:in `create'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/strategy/create.rb:12:in `block in result'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/strategy/create.rb:9:in `tap'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/strategy/create.rb:9:in `result'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/factory.rb:43:in `run'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/factory_runner.rb:29:in `block in run'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/factory_runner.rb:28:in `run'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/strategy/create.rb:5:in `association'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/evaluator.rb:33:in `association'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/attribute/association.rb:19:in `block in to_proc'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/evaluator.rb:77:in `instance_exec'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/evaluator.rb:77:in `block in define_attribute'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/attribute_assigner.rb:56:in `get'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/attribute_assigner.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in object'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/attribute_assigner.rb:15:in `each'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/attribute_assigner.rb:15:in `block in object'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/attribute_assigner.rb:14:in `tap'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/attribute_assigner.rb:14:in `object'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/evaluation.rb:13:in `object'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/strategy/create.rb:9:in `result'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/factory.rb:43:in `run'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/factory_runner.rb:29:in `block in run'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/factory_runner.rb:28:in `run'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/strategy/create.rb:5:in `association'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/evaluator.rb:33:in `association'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/attribute/association.rb:19:in `block in to_proc'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/evaluator.rb:77:in `instance_exec'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/evaluator.rb:77:in `block in define_attribute'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/attribute_assigner.rb:56:in `get'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/attribute_assigner.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in object'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/attribute_assigner.rb:15:in `each'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/attribute_assigner.rb:15:in `block in object'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/attribute_assigner.rb:14:in `tap'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/attribute_assigner.rb:14:in `object'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/evaluation.rb:13:in `object'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/strategy/create.rb:9:in `result'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/factory.rb:43:in `run'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/factory_runner.rb:29:in `block in run'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/factory_runner.rb:28:in `run'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/strategy/create.rb:5:in `association'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/evaluator.rb:33:in `association'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/attribute/association.rb:19:in `block in to_proc'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/evaluator.rb:77:in `instance_exec'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/evaluator.rb:77:in `block in define_attribute'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/attribute_assigner.rb:56:in `get'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/attribute_assigner.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in object'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/attribute_assigner.rb:15:in `each'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/attribute_assigner.rb:15:in `block in object'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/attribute_assigner.rb:14:in `tap'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/attribute_assigner.rb:14:in `object'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/evaluation.rb:13:in `object'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/strategy/create.rb:9:in `result'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/factory.rb:43:in `run'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/factory_runner.rb:29:in `block in run'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/factory_runner.rb:28:in `run'
     # /Users/evanlepolt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/factory_bot-4.8.2/lib/factory_bot/strategy_syntax_method_registrar.rb:20:in `block in define_singular_strategy_method'
     # ./spec/services/submissions/njb_soft_spec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

FactoryBot 4.8.2
Rails 5.2.2
Ruby 2.5.3

I have updated xcode, and updated/upgraded all of my homebrew pours.

The worst part about this is that I cannot reproduce the issue in a separate repository which makes me think that somewhere in our repo we're overwriting some factory_bot setting.

In Linux and Mohave this works fine, and if I remove the report from the factory and do it manually elsewhere in my spec then it works in Big Sur.

```
  test = create(:test)
  test.report = fixture_file_upload "#{Rails.root}/spec/factories/paperclip/test_report.pdf", 'application/pdf'
```

Answer (score 0):

This was neither a paperclip issue, nor a factorybot issue. My example code is incorrect in that we are using a `.tlf` file, not a pdf. Our model then validates this: `validates_attachment_content_type :report_layout, content_type: 'text/plain'`

On Big Sur mac began reading this file as json, instead of plain text.

```
file -b --mime my_file.tlf

# macOS 11.1
application/json; charset=us-ascii

# macOS 10.15.6
text/plain; charset=us-ascii

# Ubuntu 18.04
text/plain; charset=us-ascii
```

So the content type validation failed. Answer was right in front of me the whole time